# Reduce size of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput output file

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I have implemented a video recorder using AVFoundation in MAC OSX. To write the output to a file I'm using an object of AVCaptureFileOutput. On recording a 30second video the size of output file comes to 3MB which is huge. I have set capture session preset to **AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium**. I'm confused on adding settings 
`NSDictionary *videoCompressionSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                             AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:264*1000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:30], AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
 AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline30, AVVideoProfileLevelKey,
AVVideoQualityKey,nil], AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey, nil];`

to movie file output using its `setOutputSettings:forConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)>`

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: I was hoping a change to the above settings would help in reducing the size of the file.

Comment: Where did you get 264*1000 for your average bitrate from?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply control this providing the bit rate for the output

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : 400000]])
```

I wasted a ton of time becase I was directly trying to add the bit rate key property when I had to nest it under AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey

Answer (score 0):

you can change the resolution using the sessionPreset property 
**Video Input Presets**

```
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
```

use this code

```
 if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]) {
        [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
    }
```

refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html

Comment: That changes the video in a very different way than compression or frame rates. It's not necessarily a downsample either.

Comment: @uchuugaka In what way is it different? Which would you suggest for better quality?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to change the average bitrate on a file output (I used an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput in my example).

```
for connection in movieFileOutput.connections {
     let settings = movieFileOutput.outputSettings(for: connection)
     var newSettings = settings
     var sub = newSettings[AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey] as? [String: Any]
     sub![AVVideoAverageBitRateKey] = NSNumber(integerLiteral: 4000000)
     newSettings[AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey] = sub!
     movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings(newSettings, for: connection)
  }
```